# Time select field with specific values handle

Tags: php, laravel, forms, select, timepicker

In a laravel form I have a select field to select time values and i want to show from-to specific time with 30 minutes difference. Also i dont like the jquery timepicker handler so i use an array in php to feed the values.

```
$hours = array(null=>'select hour','10:00'=>'10:00','10:30'=>'10:30','11:00'=>'11:00','11:30'=>'11:30','12:00'=>'12:00','12:30'=>'12:30','13:00'=>'13:00','13:30'=>'13:30','14:00'=>'14:00','14:30'=>'14:30','15:00'=>'15:00','15:30'=>'15:30','16:00'=>'16:00','16:30'=>'16:30','17:00'=>'17:00','17:30'=>'17:30','18:00'=>'18:00');
```

That works fine, i convert string values to time and save to database.
The problem is when i edit the form and want to get values in the field but with the specific time that had been selected. How can i select the specific value.

My code in laravel form is

```
{!! Form::select('gentime', $hours, old('gentime'), ['id' => 'timefield','class' => 'form-control select']) !!}
```

Comment: In edit what is your variable name to show data that is get with the specific id

Comment: is $geg->gentime

Comment: But `$hours` is your time array, Isn't it? What is your information from your database value?

Comment: I found this but it changes the value not the key

   
$hours = array_replace($hours,array_fill_keys(array_keys($hours, substr($geg->gentime, 0, -3)),$replacement)); that finds in the arra $hours the saved value $geg->gentime and add the 'selected'.where $replacement=substr($geg->gentime, 0, -3).' selected';